# Encrypt and decrypt in assembler

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I have been working on some assembly code which encrypts something and then requires it to decrypt it again.

Here is the code, I was hoping for some help on how to write the decryption code in assembly

```
push   ebx                  
push   edx                  
push   ecx                   
movzx  edx, byte ptr[eax]   
and    edx, 0x43                 
cmp    edx, 0x00                
jnz    x16                  
mov    edx, 0x07                
inc    dl   //x16 start here
mov    dword ptr[eax], edx  
pop    ebx      
dec    ebx  //y16 start here    
dec    edx      
jnz    y16      
not    bl                               
pop    edx                              
mov    eax, ebx                         
pop    ebx                                                               
ret
```

Comment: That's not reversible for all inputs. The `and edx, 0x43` obviously only keeps 3 bits. Also the `y16` loop doesn't make sense, and writing out a dword when the input is a byte is suspicious too. I'd say it's broken code.

Answer (score 0):

Start by simplyfying the code like I did and then see where it gets you.

```
 push   ebx
 push   edx

 movzx  edx, byte ptr[eax]   
 and    dl, 0x43                 
 jnz    x16                  
 mov    dl, 0x07                
x16:
 inc    dl
 mov    dword ptr[eax], edx  ;Is this correct?

 mov    ebx, ecx
 sub    ebx, edx
 not    bl
 mov    eax, ebx

 pop    edx
 pop    ebx                                                               
 ret
```